# How many times should trackBy be called in Angular ngFor

Tags: angular

I've started using `trackBy` for some of the `ngFor` iterations in my app to improve performance.

When debugging I noticed the the `trackBy` function is called multiple times. I was in the expectation that the `trackBy` function would be called 1 x n times, where n is the number of items in the array.

I have a simple unordered list in the template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByFn">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And I return the id of the item in the `trackBy` function

```
trackByFn(index, item): void {
    return item.id;
}
```

In this StackBlitz the `trackBy` function is called 2 x n on init. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tm6zdh
In my app it is even called 7 x n times.

Is it normal the function is called multiple times?

Should I be worried about performance when the function is called multiple times?

Also, when is the `trackBy` function actually triggered by Angular? I'm asking, because in my app the `trackBy` function is also triggered when scrolling through the page, which does not update any of the items in the list. I can't reproduce it in a Stackblitz

Comment: This should be reopended - Its a very good question and very different to calling a function directly within the HTML template - I appreciate that the best solution may be similar or possibly even identical, but just because the solution is the same does not make the question the same ... e.g. Q: which band sounds like royalty A: queen Q: who is the UK monarch A: queen ... very different questions with the same answer - this is not a dupe

Answer (score 2):

It's Angular's standard change detection running. Adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the component's declaration should decrease the number of `trackBy` function calls.